# Dumbbell / Free Weights Training Programme

Tags: strength, programs, dumbbells, freeweights

I'm currently road running and swimming and I'd like to start strength training using free weights.

I have access to a set of dumbbells and would like to make use of them, but searching for starter programmes via the web seems like a difficult task due to the high amount of spam and 'amazing gains in 4 weeks' type sites.

I'm not looking to become huge - but I'd like to end up toned, stronger and fit.

What would be a good programme to follow for someone who's just starting out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first thing to know when creating a strength training program is that you need to work out all of the muscle groups to prevent injury or an awkwardly proportioned body *(you don't want to look like the Hulk up top when you look like a stick figure down below)*. This being the case, there are two ways you can approach building a workout routine:

1. Do full body routines each workout.
2. Focus on specific muscle groups each workout.

Personally, I think the "full body" approach is better for people new to strength training. There is a very good article on the Nerd Fitness website that talks about [building your own full body routine](http://nerdfitness.com/blog/2010/02/15/how-to-build-your-own-workout-routine/). An important excerpt from the article is:

> - Quads – squats, lunges, one legged squats, box jumps.
> - Butt and Hamstrings – hip raises, deadlifts, straight leg deadlifts, good mornings, step ups.
> - Push (chest, shoulders, and triceps) - overhead press, bench press, incline dumbbell press, push ups, dips.
> - Pull (back, biceps, and forearms) – chin ups, pull ups, inverse body weight rows, dumbbell rows.
> - Core (abs and lower back) – planks, side planks, exercise ball crunches, mountain climbers, jumping knee tucks, hanging leg raises.
>
> Pick one exercise from each category above for a workout, and you’ll work almost every single muscle in your body. These are just a few examples for what you can do, but you really don’t need to make things more complicated than this.

Starting off, you'll want to only do 2-3 full body workouts every week, depending on your desired intensity level. You'll also want to put a day or two of rest in between each workout so your muscles have time to recover.

Comment: This is great, thanks - think it's starting to make a difference already ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can certainly do well by doing a full body workout 3x a week and that can be an OK strategy for a beginner. You can also have good results if you set out to design your own workout plan but as you mention already, you are a beginner so chances are a plan designed by someone else with more experience would be a better fit for you.

Here are two very good free beginner workout programs:

[Men's Beginner Workout Program](http://www.weighttraining.com/workout-plans/mens-beginner-workout-plan)

[Women's Beginner Workout Program](http://www.weighttraining.com/workout-plans/womens-beginner-workout-plan)